# angularjs getting song with promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, promise

I'm sending data to a server with and JSON object using `$http.post().success().error();`

The response from the server is returning an id which is a number (example : 51)

After I get the id I'm making another request to the server. This time the data is the id that I got from the previous http call.
second http call looks something like this: `$http.get(data= Song_ID ).success().error();`

The response from the server has a `res.data.url` string,
but what the server does is that when the first http call fires, the server is creating a short music sample. This operation of course takes some time, so in the meantime the server sends back the id of the song that is being created
with that id. I want to ask the server if it's finished creating the song already.
If the `res.data.url` contains a string, it means the song is ready, if not then the operation is still working.

how do I know when the operation has completed?

For now I'm doing an interval that every second sends a http call with the song id and I'm doing an `if(res.data.url) { console.log('i have a url for you') }`

But sending lots of ajax calls with interval seems wrong to me.
is there a better way to do it?

Should I use angular promise and how?

Here's how it looks like:

```
function getId() {

            // first post to server
            var postToServer = function () {

                var song_id; // song id

                // response first time
                var onComplete = function (res) {
                    song_id = res.data.id;
                    getMySong(song_id); old stuff
                    // $location.path("/converting");
                    return res.data.id;
                };


                // error first time
                var onError = function (res) {
                    console.log(res);
                };

                var song_params = songdata.getData()["answers"].toString();

                console.log(songdata.getData()["params"]);

                var req = {
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'myserver',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    data: angular.toJson({params: "1,1,1,1,1,1"})
                };

                (function () {
                    $http(req).then(onComplete, onError);
                })();
            };

            return postToServer();
        }

        function getMySong(id) {

            var interval; // interval


             //here is that interval that checks for url
            (function () {
                interval = $interval(function () {
                    getUrlSong(id);
                }, 1000);
            })();

            // song url response
            var onResSong = function (res) {
                console.log(res);
                if (res.data.url) {
                    $interval.cancel(interval);
                    //$window.location.href = res.data.url;
                    window.songURL = res.data.url;
                    songUrl(res.data.url);
                }
            };

            // song url response error
            var onErrorSong = function (res) {
                console.log(res);
            };

            // fetch song with the id
            var getUrlSong = function (id) {
                $http.get('myserver' + id).then(onResSong, onErrorSong)
            };

        }
```

Comment: you might want to learn about [websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)

Comment: Is it possible to update the server so it won't actually send a response until the song is created? If not, @yarons is correct that websockets will allow the server to push updates to the client w/ out the need for the client to first request that data (eliminating the need to busy poll the server).